# is boiler component present in open modelica

Tags: modeling, modelica

I'm working on modeling thermal power plant. I am looking for boiler component in open modelica or ThermoPower library. Can you help me locate the boiler in modelica?

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the type of boiler (drum boiler, once-through, hot-water etc.) you are looking for and your scope/fidelity requirements (combustion model details, individual heating surfaces etc.).

Comment: Well, i am making simple steam power plant in modelica using thermo power library. I need a simple boiler for this purpose that can use pressure and enthalpy. its just an example so no specific details are there.

Answer (score 5):

There is no single boiler model present in `ThermoPower` or OpenModelica (Modelica Standard Library). However, most of the building blocks for a boiler model are available, depending on your needs:

A **very** simple boiler with feedwater pump could be written with a few code lines. E.g.

```
model SteamGenerator_ph 
  "Simple steam generator with prescribed live steam pressure and enthalpy"
  replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater;

  parameter Medium.AbsolutePressure p=1e7 "Live steam pressure";
  parameter Medium.SpecificEnthalpy h=3477e3 "Live steam enthalpy";
  parameter Real eta=0.9 "Boiler efficiency";
  Modelica.SIunits.HeatFlowRate Q_flow_fuel "Fuel heat flow rate";

  Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.FluidPort_a inlet(redeclare package Medium = Medium);
  Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.FluidPort_b outlet(redeclare package Medium = Medium);
equation 
  inlet.m_flow + outlet.m_flow = 0 "mass flow balance";

  // Energy balance
  actualStream(outlet.h_outflow)*outlet.m_flow + actualStream(inlet.h_outflow)*
    inlet.m_flow + Q_flow_fuel*eta = 0;
  inlet.h_outflow = outlet.h_outflow;

  outlet.p = p "Ideally controlled live steam pressure";
  outlet.h_outflow = h "Ideally controlled live steam enthalpy";
end SteamGenerator_ph;
```

It assumes ideally controlled live steam enthalpy and pressure so if you test it on its own you can't connect the outlet to a fixed pressure source. Instead you should fix the inlet pressure and the outlet mass flow rate. The model is very simple and might give you some problems when you close the Rankine circuit.

If you want a slightly more detailed boiler - and one that's easier to use with a turbine, preheaters etc. - you should simply use a heated pipe (boiler) connected with a (feedwater) pump and use two PI controllers to control live steam enthalpy and pressure with the pump and the heat flow rate into the pipe (see picture below). Again, since the live steam pressure is controlled you can't connect it to a pressure source.

[image]

Adding a drum+evaporator (if you are modelling a drum boiler) and a steam valve will add a bit more complexity but also flexibility in terms of testing the boiler model and connecting it to other components (se picture below for inspiration).

[image]

The `evaporation` component can be found in `Modelica.Fluid.Examples.DrumBoiler.BaseClasses.EquilibriumDrumBoiler` and is equivalent to the "simple" drum model in the ThermoPower library